# Django REST API POST pandas dataframe

Tags: django, pandas, api

I've seen several posts about Pandas dataframes and Django, but couldn't relate any to my specific problem. I'm trying to allow a user to manually create a dataframe in Python , and then make a Django API call to upload that dataframe to my Django site. I can get this to work if the user specifies a filepath, but not manual data entry. My current API Python call looks like:

```
def upload_document(user_token, filename, file_path):

    url = 'https://www.website.com/upload/' + filename + '/' 
    try:
        response = requests.post(
                    url,
                    files = {'document': open(file_path, 'rb')},
                    headers = {'Authorization': 'Token'+ ' ' + user_token}
                    )

        return(response)
    except:
        return('unable to upload document')
```

My URL is

```
url(r'^upload/(?P<filename>.+)/$', DocumentUpload.as_view(), name = "document-upload"),
```

It is uploading to a model, called Document. The API view is

```
class DocumentUpload(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
    parser_class = (FileUploadParser,)

    def post(self, request, filename, format = None, ):
        user = self.request.user
        filename = self.kwargs['filename']

        file_serializer = FileSerializer(data=request.data, context={'request': request})

        if file_serializer.is_valid():
            try:
                #file_serializer.uploaded_by = uploaded_by
                file_serializer.filename = filename


                file_serializer.save(filename = filename)

                return Response(file_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            except:
                return Response(file_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


        else:
            return Response(file_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

My serializer is

```
class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    uploaded_by = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:

        model = Document
        fields = ("id", "filename","document", "uploaded_by")
```

I can also post the model if that is important, but i dont think it is needed.

**Solution Attempt**

It seems like an easy way forward would be to simply change the python requests call `files = {'document': open(file_path, 'rb')}` to something like `files = {'document': pickle.dumps(df)}` where `df` is the user defined dataframe. This gives me a 404 error though, which i guess means that the `file_serializer` object is causing problems, specifically the `is_valid()` call. I'm not sure if i need to write another api view entirely, or if there is an easy trick to converting it into an attachable file (convert the dataframe to some filetype). Thank you for reading through this post if you've made it this far :D